# Past Alarm Trigger

Tags: android, android-alarms

Will the alarm trigger if the trigger Time is set to past Time?

For example, if the current time is 17:00 PM and if I set the alarm as 15:00 which is already passed, will the alarm be triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't.

However, if you set it at 17:00, but have your mobile shut down at that moment, and later start up your mobile at lets say 17:05, then you should get a postponed alarm.

Comment: It will if it's a repeating alarm set for a daily repeat.